# How can I export my project in Flash Builder 4 to an ant build?

Tags: apache-flex, ant, export

Greetings, 
I am developing a project with Flex, and I need to deploy my project in a form which can be used by developers who do not have access to Flash Builder. 
I've found references to plugins from Faratasystems, but it appears their sourceforge site is a little bit rusty. I could not find an up to date installation file that'd include FX2Ant plugin and work with my Flash Builder 4

Do you know any guides for this task? Any other plugins?

Best Regards
Seref

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Google is my friend, and I am a lazy, lazy person. I'd better try this one out first:
http://www.adobe.com/devnet/flex/articles/flex_ant_pt1.html